# Is there a way to determine date format in Luxon?

Tags: javascript, datetime, luxon

Example input 1: `'1 JAN'`
Expected output: `'d MMM'`

Example input 2: `'JAN 31'`
Expected output: `'MMM dd'`

Comment: The documentation is [here](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#luxon). I think the answer is "no", it's a [fool's errand](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fool%27s%20errand).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it yourself.

```js
for (let str of ['1 JAN', 'JAN 31'])
{
  console.log (str.replaceAll(/\p{L}/gu, 'M').replaceAll(/\d/g, 'd'));
}
```

Comment: So '31 December 2022' becomes 'dd MMMMMMMM dddd' when it should be 'dd MMMM YYYY'. And how does it know that 01/02/03 is dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy or yy/mm/dd or …

Comment: @RobG How should any library know it? You have to code it yourself. In general this question does not make sense. But with the limitation in the question, it can be solved. You example was not part the question.